# How to fill the Screen with ListView/GridView?

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4YWA.jpg)

how to fill the Screen?

Comment: Please copy and paste your code, not the screenshot! It is more proper to get an accepted answer.

Comment: body:    Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    children: <Widget> [
    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
    Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 15.0,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 15.0,
    child: GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    primary: false,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    children: <Widget> [

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expanded instead of Container widget to fill the screen with the ListView

Comment: I don't understand to put that in?

Comment: you need to wrap your list view with Expanded widget

Expanded(
   child:ListView...
)